# Chrome fails to load resources when using Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, response.redirect, server.transfer

This is not a "why don't my resources load in Chrome" question.

I have a site in development (VS 2015 - C#). My site starts off like this:

1. Default.aspx loads
2. Server.Transfer("view.aspx");

This works fine and all resources (jquery, bootstrap, css files, etc...) load up in I.E. but fail to load in Chrome.

I have also tried Response.Redirect("view.aspx") and get the same results.

I am passing no content from default.aspx to view.aspx, so there is nothing to preserve there.

If I set the "View.aspx" page to be the startup page, both I.E. and Chrome work fine. This would seem to indicated that my page/resources/references/etc. are fine.

So, why does Server.Transfer and/or Response/Redirect create a failure to load resources under Chrome but direct navigation seems to be fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open developers tools in your web-browser (Chrome) by pressing F12 key.
There must be tab "Network".
Look there if you got some errors on response.

Comment: Yes, I can see errors when I use the server.transfer or response.redirect. Checking F12 I can see the following:

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This does not occur if I set the view.aspx page as the start up page. (Sorry for the extra comments, I could not see how to edit this part.

Comment: Turn off "customErrors" in web.config & you will able to see why you got this error in respone.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffering this on **Server.Transfer** + *Chrome* , and my error strace shows as below:

```
Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> 
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for XXX

  at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, 
TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, 
VirtualPath 
path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String 
queryStringOverride) 
  at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(String path, TextWriter writer, 
Boolean preserveForm) 
  at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)
```

However, It works fine if I use **Response.Redirect**, and in my research, this issue may result from losing Context inform.